# check if the column is having a valid data or not in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a date column which has date in YYYYMM format when i take the data from a file but after i convert that to a dataframe i have to to check if the data is valid or not, which means i have to check whether it is in YYYYMMDD or not. Otherwise i have to replace it default date 9999-12-31. here is an example This is how my case statement has to look like--

```
case when is_valid_date(date) is not null then date else 9999-12-31.
```

I need to create a simple function called `is_valid_data` to check if the date value is valid or not

```
 input table 
 ID  date
 1  12345

 o/p expected 
 ID  date
 1  9999-12-31
```

Comment: you question is bit confusing.  is your input data is in YYYYMM or YYYYMMDD?

Comment: input data is in YYYYMM

Comment: in tat case, you can change the dateformat in my solution.. let me know if the solution worked

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question properly, below is my approach.You need not required to build a function rather you can build an expression with in-build functions and pass the expression.

```
val df = Seq("12345", "20190312", "3", "4", "5").toDF("col1")
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._


/*
* checks the given raw data is in expected date format or not.
* if not in the expected format, values are replaced with default value.
*
* Note: You need to change the dateformat according to your requirement
*/

val condExp = when(to_date(col("col1"), "yyyymmdd") isNull, lit("9999-12-31")).otherwise(col("col1"))
df.withColumn("col2", condExp).show()
```

**Result**

```
+--------+----------+
|    col1|      col2|
+--------+----------+
|   12345|9999-12-31|
|20190312|  20190312|
|       3|9999-12-31|
|       4|9999-12-31|
|       5|9999-12-31|
+--------+----------+
```